# Can I make nginx pipe files of a certain extension through another process before sending the response?

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx to serve a bunch of static files. For files of a given extension, say `.abc`, I would like to preprocess the data by piping it through another process for output. This could be used to apply format conversion, on-the-fly decryption, etc. Does nginx provide this capability natively?

Comment: AFAIK you have :  the nginx [ngx_http_sub_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) for rewriting (HTML) content  and [njs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/njs/index.html) and lua: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/dynamic-modules/lua/ add pre-processing and additional customisation

Comment: i am unsure who downvoted this, but it is a good question in my point of view.